# WebView not responding to Keyboard input

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, webview

I cannot seem to type into WebView no matter how I load the url. Using either `loadRequest` or `takeStringURLFrom`. It does not seem to respond to keyboard input.

I have not done anything fancy:

```
var url = "http://www.google.com"
var requestUrl = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
webViewMain.mainFrame.loadRequest(requestUrl)
```

The WebView is ok with mouse clicks and scrolling but does not respond to keyboard.

Comment: is it not responing on device or simulator?

Comment: EDIT: This is referring to a Mac OSX Application not an IOS Application

Comment: @ReneGAED Oh! Ok. I doesn't know that.

Comment: Thank you that was the issue!

Comment: @ReneGAED can you provide solution? Struggling with this as well.